# HTML5 Video Tag and Android WebView, preload is not working

Tags: android, video, webview, html5-video

I am trying to show first one second of video frame as the preview of video.
But unfortunately, it doesn't show rather than black screen unless play the video. Help me!

My html

```
<a class="att_mov" href="{$path}">
    <video preload="metadata">
        <source src="{$path}#t=1">
    </video>
</a>
```

My Android Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MainActivity.MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(myURL);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    }
}
```

Expected result:

[image]

Current result:

[image]

Comment: The question has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220624/android-webview-gray-play-button

Answer (score 1):

I have a long time with this error. My solution was to pass it on poster = "null", because it seems that the web puts that poster by default.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If You use Mobile data then you will get a black screen. but instead if you try to load with wifi then the thumbnail for the video will appear. the main reason for this preload="auto" this cause the thumbnail to shown when we have wifi but not load thumbnail when we use mobile data.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your experience with me. But I am running my project only by using wifi network. No thumbnail is appeared till now.